# Console.log javascript not working in web browser

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to use console log to log the date in the console log but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(new Date());
},1000);
```

As you see this code is simple and should run because no syntax errors that are there. But when i use Firefox console log i should see the new date popping every 1 second. But i get these errors:

1. SyntaxError: syntax error
2. SyntaxError: syntax error
3. The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with that code the errors are coming from the other code on the site that you are running that in. Open up a console in stackoverflow or any site without script errors and it will run fine

Comment: `console.log` depends on the browser. IE has a problem with it as i recall

Comment: so what should I do for that code to run?

Comment: please post the rest of the code on the page

Comment: It seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/0vtpadyf/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have an encoding issue in your .html (or js) file.
Just use an editor like notepad++, go to Menu then Encoding, and try to select UTF8.

Additionaly you may specify the encoding in your html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```